# Interpolation between ECDF curves

Tags: matlab, linear-interpolation, ecdf

I have 6 curves which describes the ECDF of number of tickets bought at a fix value. [image: ECDF Curves]

Now I want to interpolate to make curves between them, but following the next formula. For example to estimate the ECDF at a prices of 10k, should be guide by F(10k)=αF1+(1-α)F2; with 0<α<1 . The curves I'd plotted I got it by ecdf function. I have trying doing interp1 to simulate observation but it haven't work for me to simuate observations for a new price.

So I tried with the codes made by @rayryeng

> max_len = max(numel(F1),numel(F2));
>   F1_interp = interp1(1:numel(F1), F1(:).', linspace(1,numel(F1),max_len));
>   F2_interp = interp1(1:numel(F2), F2(:).', linspace(1,numel(F2),max_len));

alpha = (10e3 - 9.5e3) / (11e3 - 9.5e3);
Fnew = alpha*F1_interp + (1-alpha)*F2_interp;

and get the next curve[image: Fnew]

But plotting the curves with F1 and F2 it doesn't seems to ve between or either a interpolation of those.[image: plotting curves]

Comment: I don't think you're using my code properly.  The curves of `F1` and `F2` have around 300 elements yet your curve for `Fnew` is 25 elements.  Can you provide what `F1` and `F2` are in your post?

Comment: F1 and F2 doesn't add more than 53 elements. Let me poste the data, you would se that both columns aren't the same length
F1 F2
24 59
4 9
208 5
225 6
6 69
2 28
12 191
4 4
66 23
19 39
22 194
53 2
129 40
86 55
78 2
26 262
56 41
2 63
7 62
6 163
10 5
 14
 10
 4
 13
 1
 61
 2
 2
 4

Comment: OK.  I seem to have misunderstood the `x` axis.  What values are along the `x` axis?  Do you have those available?

Comment: The only data I manage it is the posted before, then I use the ecdf function to the data 
> a1 = xlsread('Data.xlsx');
>[f1,x1] = ecdf(a1(:,[1]));
so in the x axis there are the data posted before which was
>2
2
4
6
7
10
12
19
22
24
26
53
56
66
78
86
129
208
225
(I can't post in the correct way the data and codes)

Comment: I plot F1 and F1_interp  and it gave me the same curve (plot(F1), plot(F1_interp)), the thing is that I can't plot F1_interp with the others 2 because didn't interpolate the x data of F1_interp1. So to verify if the Fnew it is between F1 and F2, I need to found the way to obtain its x axis

Comment: Finally undesrtand my error, once I interpolate the Fs, and get the Fnew, to plot the new curve and see if it fits to the others I should have interpolate also the x axis in order to follow the Fnew, with its corresponding Xnew data

Comment: Ah yes, you need to do that.  Sorry, I was unavailable earlier today because I'm working.  I'm glad you figured it out!

Comment: I really appreciate your help! thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you follow that formula, then `interp1` isn't needed at all.  You can just get `F(10k)` by seriously just computing `alpha*F1 + (1-alpha)*F2` with `alpha` being between `[0,1]`... if I'm interpreting your question correctly.

In the case of `alpha`, that is a fraction between the value seen at `F1` and the value seen at `F2`.  In your case, this is simple as:

```
alpha = (ffnew - ff1) / (ff2 - ff1)
```

`ff1` and `ff2` are the prices in between the value you want, which is `ffnew`.  You can verify that if `ffnew = ff1`, then `alpha = 0` and you get the original `F2` curve.  Similarly, if `ffnew = ff2`, then `alpha = 1` and so you'd get the original `F1` curve.  Any price value in between `F1` and `F2`, you just have to be judicious on how you specify `alpha`.

Therefore, `alpha` for your case of `ff1 = 9.5k` and `ff2 = 11k` and `fnew = 10k`  would be:

```
alpha = (10e3 - 9.5e3) / (11e3 - 9.5e3) = 0.33333...
```

Therefore, assuming `F1` and `F2` are the curves at `9.5k` and `11k` respectively:

```
alpha = (10e3 - 9.5e3) / (11e3 - 9.5e3);
Fnew = alpha*F1 + (1-alpha)*F2;
```

---

The above assumes that your signals are the same length.  If they aren't, then you have to interpolate the smaller signal so that it matches in length with the larger signal.  `interp1` is the tool to use here (IMHO).  You would specify the key / control points as the points from `F1`.  However, `interp1` requires `(x,y)` pairs and we don't have any `x` values.... the `y` values though are from `F1`.  Therefore, you'd artificially create `x` values to be a numeric vector that is increasing.  The simplest one I can think of is a vector from 1 up to as many values as there are in smaller signal.  To expand the signal, you'd generate another vector that is again from 1 up to as many values in the smaller signal, but we'd create the number of points to be the larger signal with `linspace`.

As such, try something like this:

```
max_len = max(numel(F1),numel(F2));
F1_interp = interp1(1:numel(F1), F1(:).', linspace(1,numel(F1),max_len));
F2_interp = interp1(1:numel(F2), F2(:).', linspace(1,numel(F2),max_len));

alpha = (10e3 - 9.5e3) / (11e3 - 9.5e3);
Fnew = alpha*F1_interp1 + (1-alpha)*F2_interp2;
```

The first line of code finds the largest of the two lengths of the signals.  Next we ensure that both `F1` and `F2` are the same length.  The effect is that one of these won't change but the other one will to expand to match the larger signal.  The above is to ensure that both signals are the same length, regardless of what `F1` and `F2` are.  Once you do this, you can apply the operations we talked about above as normal on the new signals.

Comment: Agreed, you correctly understand my question. The thing is I tried to writing like that but it showed an error:
'Error using  + 
Matrix dimensions must agree' .
So writting the formua like that don't know if it will give a vector or the graphic of a middle curve between F1 and F2

Comment: Ahhh I assumed that they were the same length. In general I'm assuming that each signal isn't?

Comment: Exactly, that's because those are observation given by a period of time in which the observers couldn't change the prices too often to get same number of observation by each price. Should I fill the vectors with zeros or there is a function to do what I'm looking for?

Comment: Ah ok. Then definitely interpolation is required. You'd have to take the shorter signal and interpolate so it matches in length with the larger signal then it will work. Let me modify my post.

Comment: @ChristianNoack - Try now.

Comment: Perfect, I'm trying it right now. One of the observation I could do is that I can't plot Fnew whit F1 and F2 because it need to have the same length, as matlab says. I will post the image that I got of Fnew and try to plot with F1 and F2 to see if it fits in the middle

Comment: You can still use `interp1`, and look at the `extrap` flag so you can extrapolate data.

Comment: I was trying now to extrapolate the same data. i'm trying something like this (having the same variables than before)
>[F2, dup] = unique(F2);
>x2 = x2(dup);
>randomValues = rand(1, 1000);
>Fextrap = interp1(F2,x2,'linear','extrap')
What I'm trying to make is, given F1=9,5k and F2=11K, I want to reach the curve Fextrap=15k, but I'm not shure doing it right cause I don't know where to mention to Matlab that Fextrap=15k.
If you could help me it would be great! @SOreadyohelp

Comment: @ChristianNoack - I would recommend you choose two curves which contain `15k` then use the above methodology the interpolate.  I don't think extrapolation is going to work given your relationship between the two curves.

Comment: But, what if in this case I doesn't have any more curves to be between 15k. It's almost like doing a forecast but "extrapolating" it

Comment: @ChristianNoack - I'm not sure how to approach it TBH.